# How do I process data that isn't sliced by time in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-data-factory

So I am trying to use Azure Data Factory to replace the SSIS system we have in place, and I am having some trouble...

The process I want to follow is to take a list of projects and a list of clients and create a report of the clients and projects we have. These lists update frequently, so I want to update this report every hour. To combine the data, I will be using Power BI Pro, so Data Factory just needs to load the data into a usable format.

My source right now is a call to an API that returns a list of projects. However, this data isn't separated by time at all. I don't see any sort of history. Same goes for the list of clients.

What should the availability for my dataset be?

Answer (score 0):

you may use the custom activity in ADF to call the API that returns list of projects. The custom activity will then write that data in the right format to the destination.

Example of a custom activity in ADF: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/

The frequency will be the cadence at which you wish to run this operation.